# AngularJS, Jasmine and $ressource = promise not resolved

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have problems to build a jasmine test on top of a mocked resource factory.

The (working) Scenario:

Controller:

```js
.controller("remoteCtrl", function(resourceFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.animals = resourceFactory.getAll();
});
```

Factory

```js
        .factory('resourceFactory', function ($resource) {
            var demoResource = $resource('/demo-1.0/webresources/animal/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
                getAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                getFirst: {method: 'GET', params: {id: 0}, isArray: false},
                save: {method: 'POST', params: {id: null}}
            });

            return demoResource;
        });
```

MockModule for Backendless Development:

```js
angular.module('playAngular.mock', ['ngMockE2E'])

        .run(function ($httpBackend, $log) {

            var animals = [
                {name: 'Animal1', age: '100', id: 0},
                {name: 'Animal2', age: '100', id: 1},
                {name: 'Animal3', age: '100', id: 2},
                {name: 'Animal4', age: '100', id: 3}
            ];

            $httpBackend.whenGET('/demo-1.0/webresources/animal').respond(function () {
                return [200, animals];
            });
  //....
```

That is working fine all together. But now the problematic point. I want to test my Controller with Jasmin:

```js
describe("Test Suite für RemoteController", function () {
    beforeEach(module('ngResource'));
    beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));
    beforeEach(module('playAngular.mock'));
    beforeEach(module('playAngular.remote'));
    
    var $controller;
    var $scope;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    var controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        controller = $controller('remoteCtrl', {$scope: $scope});

    });

    describe("Basic Remote Test", function () {
        it('Test It:', function () {
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
            expect(controller.animals).toBe(4);
        });
    });
});
```

The test will fail:

> **Expected [ $promise: Promise({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }) }), $resolved: false ] to be 4.**

I understand the error, we have an unresolved promise here, but how can i get it working to wait and test the repond in jasmine test?
This one:

```
        controller.animals.$promise.then(function(result){
             expect(result.length).toBe(4);
        });
```

won't work as well (jasmine doesn't wait for the response and just returns with "all fine".

I try all hints I found in web: trigger digest cycle, flush httpbackend, but nothing worked. Does somebody see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

All Examples i found so far are based on mocking the ressource and not using the ngMockE2E.

Somethink like that:

```
    beforeEach(function () {
    var resourceFactoryTest={
        getAll: function() {return [{id: 1}];},
        getFirst: function(){return [{id: 1}];} 
    };
    controller = $controller('remoteCtrl', {$scope: $scope, resourceFactory: resourceFactoryTest});
});
```

That will work (of course) = we do not have any real ressource-promised to worry about. But my aim is again to use my backendless development module (based on ngMockE2E), which produces all my local test data for the jasmin test instead of creating test data again in the jasmin tests itself.

Based on a blog post : [Blog](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/16/unit-test-http-ngmock-passthrough/) i assume that both module ngMock and ngMockE2E "normally" won't work together. The solution there is based on a custome little hack which may be working (i don't tested it)
For now i ended up with a central "MockDataRessource" which is just a factory to produce my test data, which i now use in the ngMockE2E and testing functions. Not perfect but working.